# Bind Details view with class object

Tags: vb.net

How can I bind the details view and return a class object?

```
Dim _obj As New NewRequestDetailsBL

_obj = NewRequestDetailsBL.SelectRequestDetails(Session("requestid"), 
Session("contactid"))
dvAdmin1.DataSource = _obj ' this line is giving the error
dvAdmin1.DataBind()
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Data source is an invalid type.  
It must be either  an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error contains every information you need!

> It must be either  an [IListSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or [IDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.idatasource.aspx).

Your class has to implement at least one of these interfaces and then you'll be able to set `DataSource` to an instance of `NewRequestDetailsBL` class.